# Evaluate in property getter or when creating an instance?

Tags: c#

Ok, an easy question.

First of all, I have to say that my concern *is not* performance. I'm totally aware that whatever performance costs one option or the other may entail are probably meaningless and not even worth considering in normal scenarios. It has more to do with design standards and curiosity as to how the majority of coders would do it.

Ok, so the question is rather simple:

Suppose I have a *ComplexNumber* `struct` which I could implement the following way:

```
public struct Complex : IEquatable<Complex>, IFormattable
{
    readonly double realPart, imaginaryPart, magnitude, argument;
    readonly static Complex j = new Complex(0, 1);

    public Complex(double realPart, double imaginaryPart)
    {
        this.realPart = realPart;
        this.imaginaryPart = imaginaryPart;
        this.magnitude = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(realPart, 2) + Math.Pow(imaginaryPart, 2));
        this.argument = Math.Atan2(imaginaryPart, realPart);
    }

    public double RealPart { get { return this.realPart; } }
    public double ImaginaryPart { get { return this.imaginaryPart; } }
    public double Magnitude { get { return this.magnitude; } }
    public double Argument { get { return this.argument; } }

    public static Complex J { get { return Complex.j; } }
    ...
 }
```

The `Magnitude` and `Argument` properties have backing fields that are evaluated at construction time. Another option would be to simply evaluate the corresponding value in either getter.

What is the most recommended way to do this? Is there any coding standard that recommends any option for the sake of having a standard? And if there isn't one, what is normally the preferred choice? Or is it only performance dependant which in my case is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED BELOW:]

Why evaluate in the getter and not in the setter? I would evaluate the value as it is being set. That way the correct value can be used in private methods.

Set defaults in c'tor, evaluate in setter.

You will always read the value more often than setting it, so for performance reasons you should do the evaluation in the setter - it will be run less often.

[UPDATE:]
If the property is read-only then evaluate in the c'tor, for the same reasoning as above (performance - you will only do the evaluation once). I know you say performance is not an issue, but if there are no reasons not to do it in the better performing way then it should be done like that.

Comment: I don't follow you. This is an immutable type, there are no setters. The question is if choosing the option of initializing the corresponding fields in the constructor and then making them available through a getter or simply choosing to have no backing field and evaluate everytime in the getter.

Comment: @InBetween, no, I don't follow you. You are talking about setters in your answer.

Comment: @svick: Sorry, my comment was for *hofnarwillie*. I'm most definitely not talking about *setters* in my question.

Comment: Yes I have revised my answer because I see now that you are talking about readonly properties. Please see the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I would favor computing the values directly in getters, because it's more readable: If you want to know what `Argument` does, just look at its code. If you cached the value in a field like you do now, you have to go `Argument` property → `argument` field → constructor.

If performance did matter, obviously the proper way to find out which option is better in your case is profiling. But as a *guess*, I think the version with values cached in fields will be slower too, especially if you don't use the computed values often. That's because `struct`s are copied all the time and those fields make the `struct` twice as big.

Comment: Readable code is always a plus, and yes, having the getters do the work does make the code easier to read and figure out what its doing at a simple glance. Of course in such a simple type this might be a minor factor but still something to keep in mind.

Comment: @svick: if only this code is considered, putting code in getter is fine. but considering it as general rule, i won't prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

`C'tor` should initialize the members with default values.

Definitely, performance can become issue if you move the code to getter because you'll evaluate each time getter is called.

However, The contract of getter says that it'll get the value. so calculation part should be avoided as much as possible in getter block.

And you should also try to avoid the use of dirty values. if you set the `Magnitude`(say) in getter but try to access it within class directly; you might end-up in using wrong value.

Hence, if the question is about initilizing member variables, do it in c'tor. that's why it is created by language designers.

Comment: The question is not about initializing member variables. That question is moot when it comes to *value types* as it is *mandatory* to do so. The question is if it's worth having the member variables to begin with.

Comment: I disagree that calculation should be avoided in getters. Especially if it's relatively simple code like here.

Comment: @InBetween: Yes, if memory is not an issue. it'll be more scalable as requirements change.

Comment: @svick: Well, actual answer is, it depends. but most of the times we should do so, if possible.